# R pass further argument to function

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function like this:

```
myFunction <- function(x, y, z) {
    value <- lapply(x, function(x) {
                           value <- otherFunction(y, z, k, j)
                           return(value)
                       }
             )
}
```

Is there a way to "use" the k and j parameters of the function called within lapply, without explicitly writing them into the argument part of myFunction?

**EDIT**

This could be a running example:

```
myl <- list(A=c(1:20), B=c(10:30), C=c(20:40))

myFunction <- function(l, ...){
    value <- lapply(l, function(x, ...){
        log(x, base=exp(100))
    })
    return(value)
}

myFunction(l=myl)
```

The thing I would know is if it is possible to change the `base` parameter of the `log` function even if it is not explicitly declared into the function argument `myFunction <- function(l, ...)`.

All the best

Comment: It will be easier with a reproducible example, but maybe you can check `...`

Comment: where would the value of `k` come?

Comment: K is a value of the function called by lapply.

Comment: I edited the post with a running example. It is very easy, but I think it clarifies the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand you, but I think this is what you want

```
myFunction <- function(l, ...){
  value <- lapply(l, function(x){
    log(x, ...)
  })
  return(value)
}
```

Then you can run it (for example)

```
myFunction(l = myl, base = exp(100))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Due to your example I finally understand how to use the three "magic" dots!